# How do you write a field that can allow both username and email address in an html form

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I would like to insert a field that can accept both the username and email address in the html form!

```
<label>Username or e-mail address: </label>
<input type="text">
```

Also I believe there a need for Javascript used for validation.

Comment: "I would like to insert a field that can accept both the username and email address in the html form!" — Well, you have a freeform text field, so you have one. What's the problem?

Comment: "Also I believe there a need for Javascript used for validation." — Are you asking us if your belief is right? Have you confirmed that it is needed by whomever is defining your project requirements? What **specific** problem are you having? There are no shortage of tutorials on "how to validate forms with JavaScript" out there. Nor how to check if a string is an email address. "Is a valid username" is harder… but mostly because we don't know what the requirements for a username on your system are.

Answer (score 0):

Give your input an id:

```
<input type="text" id="inputID" />
```

You can use jQuery to check if inputID is an email:

```
var inputId = $('#inputID').val();

if (inputId.indexOf('@') > -1)
{
  alert("this is an email");
} else {
  alert("this is not an email");
}
```

You can set the variable using JavaScript if you don't like jQuery.  You just have to use getelementbyId.

Comment: Loading jQuery just to get the effect of `querySelector` is a really bloated approach. This also will claim that `@example` is an email.

Comment: Please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the element by id:

```
<input type="text" id="input" />


const regEx = new RegExp('^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')

const inputElement = document.getElementById('input');
if(inputElement && inputElement.value){
  if(inputElement.value.match(regEx)
    console.log('Is Email')
  else
    console.log('Is Username')
}
```

The Regex checks if the input is an email or username.

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.